# android socket TCP line terminator

Tags: android, sockets, buffer, terminator

How do I tell

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

to stop reading to the buffer when it encounters line terminal "\r\n"?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
String strLine = null;

//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null  )   {
        if(strLine.contains("\r\n")){
                break;
             }


        }// end while

         in.close();
         ...
```

Comment: technically, calling `in.readLine()` itself means that the line was terminated by a new line escape sequence.

Comment: I did not explained myself correctly. I have a server who is always sending "%d\r\n", and every time the client receives this characters I want it to present i on the screen. the problem is that the  BufferedReader is reading it's maximum size, and only letting me read "in" and pass it to the UI thread after storing data to its maximum capacity. What I want is to be to tell BufferedReader to go to the next line of code every time it reads \r\n. Is there a way to the BufferedReader not to read to its maximum capacity but to read to buffer until \r\n?

Comment: You already read line by line. The \n indicates the end of a line so readLine() will end there. If your want to add the lines together then do line + "\n"; See my other reply.